# Unalble to deploy application created in VS2015 using TFS2013 with Release Manager 2015

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, ms-release-management

I have an application written using Visual Studio 2015 which we are trying to deploy to our server farm using TFS2013 and Release Manager 2015. All of our other applications were written using VS2013. We are getting the following error.

```
Exception Message: Release build failed (type Exception)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

Any suggestions to fix this?

Log from TFS:

```
00:34
Overall Build Process

00:34
Overall build process

00:00
Update build number

00:33
Run on agent (reserved build agent Default Agent - fedvwebslk01)

00:00
Initialize environment

00:10
Get sources from Team Foundation Version Control
Shelveset Gated_2015-10-27_05.02.55.6477;FTBCO\24287 for request 769 has been approved for check-in.

00:00
Associate the changesets that occurred since the last good build

00:19
Compile, Test and Publish

00:00
Run optional script before MSBuild

00:17
Run MSBuild

00:16
Built $/FNS/Arx/ARXAdmin/DEV/FHN.ARX.AdminWeb.sln for default targets.

00:15
Built $/FNS/Arx/ARXAdmin/DEV/FHN.ARX.AdminWeb/FHN.ARX.AdminWeb.csproj for default targets.
MSBuild Log File

00:00
Run optional script after MSBuild

00:02
Process the release

00:00
Get the Build Directory

00:00
If ProcessReleaseTokens is set

00:00
Initialize tokens

00:00
Prepare folder to search

00:00
Find all .token files

00:00
Process each .token file

00:00
Rename files

00:00
Assign

00:00
Remove read-only flag from x.y

00:00
Copy x.y.token to x.y
D:\Builds\1\FNS\FHN.ARX.AdminWeb Dev CI\src\FHN.ARX.AdminWeb\Web.config

00:00
Rename files

00:00
Assign

00:00
Remove read-only flag from x.y

00:00
Copy x.y.token to x.y
D:\Builds\1\FNS\FHN.ARX.AdminWeb Dev CI\src\FHN.ARX.AdminWeb\FHN.ARX.AdminWeb\Web.config

00:02
If ReleaseBuild is set

00:02
Try to release the build

00:00
Get the build details

00:01
Initialize release build variables

00:00
Get the Release Management install directory

00:00
Verify the Release Management install directory

00:00
Get the Release Management install directory (x64)

00:00
Get the Team Project Collection instance

00:00
If ConfigurationsToRelease is not set

00:01
Copy binaries to drop

00:01
Process each ConfigurationsToRelease

00:01
Release the build

00:01
Run the Release Management build process for the current configuration

Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Build starting process...
Processing using the following parameters:
TeamFoundationServerUrl:                http://fedvshpapp01:8080/tfs/fhn
TeamProjectName:                        FNS
TeamProjectWithCollection:              fhn/FNS
BuildDefinitionName:                    FHN.ARX.AdminWeb Dev CI
BuildNumber:                            FHN.ARX.AdminWeb Dev CI_20151027.9
TargetStage:                            Dev

Creating the release and waiting for deployment result...

ERROR: No release template matching the current build definition was found to create a release and deployment for.
Exit: 1

00:00
If a Release Build error cccurs

00:00
Release build failed
 Exception Message: Release build failed (type Exception)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

00:00
Handle Exception

00:00
Create a bug for the build failure

00:00
Rethrow the exception so the build will stop

00:02
Perform Final Actions On Agent

00:02
Copy binaries to drop

00:00
Reset the Environment
```

Comment: Look at the release log in Release Management.

Comment: It dose'nt get that far? It builds fine locally but fails the build compile. Added the log from TFS above.

Comment: Amazing how people down vote a post without even saying why or offering a suggestion. Great way to get people to use stack.

Comment: Is it a vNext release template? If not, is the "Allow release to be triggered from build" checkbox set in the release template properties?

Comment: It is not a vNext template and Allow release to be triggered is checked. The odd thing is that solutions created using VS2013 depoly just fine.

Comment: I had a similar issue regarding this and my problem was TeamFoundationServerUrl does not recognize my template. In your RM config, is your TFS link equals of build template?